# how to integrate tcpdf with magento?

Tags: magento, tcpdf, zend-pdf

I have problems with arabic characters in pdfs when printing invoices
the problem seem to relate to the pdf lib of zend
so i decide to use tcpdf

now most blogs about this just explain the steps to but tcpdf at your lib and call it from your code

but i don’t know where to call it and use it to create my custom pdf then output the pdf

i tried to call it from the get Pdf function from this file

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

but i didn’t work, it gives me an error says something is already outputed

where should i use the tcpdf lib and disable the functionality of the default pdf zend lib?

thanks